# QGIS export to PDF - rasterize only basemap layers but keep others as vectors

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, rasterization, basemap

I am building my own map in QGIS 3.4 in which I created a basemap from ESRI satellite imagery and a ESRI hillshade overlay. On top I have several custom vector layers (country borders, city names etc.)

When exporting the map to PDF, I would like to keep the vector information of labels, borders, lines etcetera to ensure sharpness. The background basemap layers however can (and should) be merged rasterized. Is there a way to only rasterize certain layers to when exporting?